# How to change the default node order for different partition?

Tags: slurm

For example, I have two partitions, **high** and **low**, each has same nodes node[1-10], When we submit a job to **high** partition the nodes order is node1,node2......node10,  when we submit a job to **low** partition, the order is node10,node9......node1.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: This is a good question. This seems to be what others call "Dual-Ended Scheduling" (see this paper by Scott Atchley https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7877165/). This paper has been recently discussed on Beowulf mailing list (http://beowulf.org/pipermail/beowulf/2018-June/034962.html). Did you try specifying the list of nodes in the partition specification, e.g. `PartitionName=high Nodes=node[1-10]` and `PartitionName=low Nodes=node10,node9,...`?